# UIAlertController showing with delay

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm experiencing a problem with UIAlertController on my app now migrated to iOS8 with Date Picker inside.

Below is the code.

```
UIAlertController *AlertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

 UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
{
[AlertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

 UIAlertAction *set = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Set to today", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
{
[self set_to_today:nil];
[AlertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}];

 UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
{
[AlertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];


 UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker setDate:data_appo];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[AlertView.view addSubview:datePicker];
[AlertView addAction:ok];
[AlertView addAction:set];
[AlertView addAction:cancel];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:datePicker];
[self presentViewController:AlertView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UIAlertController and Date Picker is shown when the user select a row from UITableViewController.

The problem is the following:
first time the users select the row everything works fine...but if the user select "Cancel" and then select de tate again the UIAlertController takes 2-3 seconds to show up...this happens also in the simulator...

I'm getting crazy....this makes my app have a bad user experience.

Any help will be strongly appreciated
Thanks

Alex

Comment: Try to replace `self` with `AlertView` in the line with `bringSubviewToFront` and call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on `self`.

Comment: Replacing self with AlertView mouthing changes.

Comment: If I call "dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: on self" i get an error...not sure if i'm coding correctly...can you post a sample code?

Answer (score 92):

I was having the same issue with a UIAlertController presented by selecting a row from a UITableView. The first time everything worked fine, and then when the user triggered the alert again there was a few seconds delay before the alert was actually presented.

As a workaround I used GCD:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:AlertView animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

It is probably a bug since `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is already executed on the main thread.

I submitted a bug report to Apple: [rdar://19285091](http://openradar.appspot.com/19285091)

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to fix my problem. Still takes 3 seconds to show the alert.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem with a table view. Thanks, your solution worked for me.

Comment: still its getting delay

Comment: same here, alert on table view cell click... not fully solving the problem but makes it better

Comment: I also come across this problem, has not yet been solved

Comment: Yeah, definitely a bug. Using iOS 9.1 and still has this issue. Using dispatch_async seemed to resolve it. Probably will create a category item. Ugly solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: Annoying bug! This solution is a gimmick, but fixed my problem successfully! (tested on iOS 8.4 and 9.1) Thanks!!

Comment: This solution worked for me. Not quite sure why, since nothing should be done in the background here. Oh well...

Comment: This solved me also the case dismissing a modal on didSelectItem had a delay, with this code is fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: my delay was like 2-3 seconds and this worked for me. thanks

Comment: What the hell? Fixed my delay, how is that even possible?

Comment: Worked Like charm. Thanks

Comment: Dispatching code on main thread worked for me, but I dont know wht this problem happened, since didSelectRow is already called on main thread.

Comment: Worked on iOS 10.3! Thanks!

Comment: Sigh, still needed as of iOS 11.x... Very weird indeed, since setting a breakpoint and checking the call stack reveals that `didSelectRow:` is already being executed on the **main** thread...

Comment: In my case, I was presenting a **custom** modal view controller using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` etc. so it took me checking my own code thoroughly before I tried replacing it with a stock, vanilla `UIAlertController` and notice the delay was still there...

Answer (score 27):

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
```

Swift 3.0 version. Alternatively, setting animated: false also solved my problem.