# How to remove delay from UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

After I tap table cells, I am getting a delay of 4 to 5 seconds for the alert view to display. Below is the code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    })
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})
   alertController.addAction(ok)
   alertController.addAction(cancel)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How to avoid this delay?

Comment: Does animation seems slow?

Comment: No, it is the action methods which need to be displayed, that is 'Ok', and 'Cancel' in alert controller.

Comment: Are you on a background thread anywhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When we deal with UI, then its important that it must be done on main tread.
So just copy your code of showing alert and paste in dispatch main thread block.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    })
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
})
   alertController.addAction(ok)
   alertController.addAction(cancel)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This should not be necessary since the table view delegate methods should only be called on the main queue. @leaner122 Are you explicitly calling the didSelectRowAt delegate method yourself?

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, it shouldn't be necessary. However I'm experiencing the same behaviour, and I can see it's already on the main thread when it creates the UIAlertViewController and presents it, but I experienced the same issue which was resolved with the dispatch. Likely a bug, and an old one at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449724/uialertcontroller-showing-with-delay

Comment: You are absolutely right, this does fix it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Write code in main queue to present UIAlertViewController.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //Write your code here.
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?